# What is the correspondence between the date of ISA_A64_xml_A_profile and the issue of Arm Architecture Reference Manual for A-profile architecture?

Tags: arm

I am relatively new to Arm documents (PDF, XML, HTML).

To study Arm A-profile architecture I use the following documents:

1. Arm Architecture Reference Manual for A-profile architecture (issue I.a)
2. Descriptions in XML and HTML format for the Armv8-A and Armv9-A A64 Instruction Set Architecture
   (`ISA_A64_xml_A_profile-2023-03.tar.gz`)

In the 1. in the Release history we see that issue I.a dated "19 August 2022" and represents "Armv9 EAC release" (though I don't know yet what does "EAC" stand for).

In the 2. we see that the date is "2023-03".

Now the core question: how to I know to which issue (e.g. I.a) of Arm Architecture Reference Manual for A-profile architecture the `ISA_A64_xml_A_profile-2023-03.tar.gz` is related to?

In other words: what is the correspondence between the date of ISA_A64_xml_A_profile and the issue of Arm Architecture Reference Manual for A-profile architecture?

For example:

```
<ISA_A64_xml_A_profile date>  <Arm Architecture Reference Manual for A-profile architecture issue>
2023-03                       I.a
2022-09                       H.a
...
```

UPD: Observation: E1.3.11, "Generation of specific floating-point values" seems forgot to list `FPOnePointFive`.